# Applying media-query in Sass if-check not working

Tags: sass, media-queries

I have this tiny Sass helper-function:

```
$sides: (top, bottom, left, right);
$space-values: (0, 2, 5, 10, 15, 17, 20, 22, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 120);

@each $side in $sides {
  @for $i from 1 through length($space-values) {
   .m-#{str-slice($side, 0, 1)}-#{nth($space-values, $i)} {
    margin-#{$side}: #{nth($space-values, $i)}px;
    margin-#{$side}: rem-calc(nth($space-values, $i), $base-font-size);
    // Apply media-query if space-value is above 80
    @if #{nth($space-values, $i)} > 80 and $side == top or bottom {
     @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
       margin-#{$side}: 60px;
     }
  }
}
```

What it does is iterate over the space-values and create a bunch of margin-classes to apply in the markup. However, I want to make the margin (top and bottom) default to 60 pixels on smaller devices if it oversteps 80px. The problem is it's not working correctly.

What happens is it applies the media-query to all the different margin-classes, it doesn't matter if it's 2px or 90px. This doesn't work:

```
  @if #{nth($space-values, $i)} > 80 and $side == top or bottom {
     @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
       margin-#{$side}: 60px;
     }
  }
```

Can anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 small mistakes into your `@if` statement:

1. You're using interpolation `#{nth($space-values, $i)}` which is mean to be used only for generating content
2. You have incorrect condition `$side == top or bottom` where you mean "if `$size` is either `top` or `bottom`" but due to missed condition its actual meaning is "if `$size` is `top` or string `bottom` is value that resolves to `true`".

Because of last mistake your whole condition always resolves into `true`. Correct condition is:

```
@if nth($space-values, $i) > 80 and ($side == top or $side == bottom) {
    @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
        margin-#{$side}: 60px;
    }
}
```